# JBoss Fuse, creating container with ActiveMQ

Tags: java, docker, activemq-classic, jbossfuse, apache-servicemix

We are using JBoss Fuse 6.2 (in Docker, but it's outscoped here). We are creating a container with the command:

```
bin/admin create $containername
```

We have two scenarios:
We start container with the command:

```
/bin/admin start $containername
```

This way, activemq is not activated at all.

The other scenario is starting the container without parameters:

```
./bin/start
```

This way, the container will activate ActiveMq.
Please help me understand the behavior: the same created container will activate ActiveMQ if started with bin/start, but won't activate if started with bin/admin/start $containername?

Side question: when creating a container with bin/admin/create, is activemq installed by default or not?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `bin/start` you create a standalone Fuse container with things like Camel and ActiveMQ installed.

Using `bin/admin start <name>` you create a new empty Karaf container that you'll need to provision yourself.

**Solution**: only use `bin/start`.